# Google Analytics request object thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, google-analytics, x509certificate2

I'm using [this](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Analytics_1_1v3_1_1DataResource_1_1GaResource_1_1GetRequest.html) request object when reading GA data from .NET. The plan is to create the request in a static constructor for usage in an ASP.NET web page as a static member - to save time. I do not mind that the certificate stays in memory.

The embedded [X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be thread safe under these conditions (used in a static condition). But I can't seem to find any reference about the GA request object.

It works in test setups but I need to be sure this is by design. Anyone knows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [AnalyticsService](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Analytics_1_1v3_1_1AnalyticsService.html) which creates the Request object implements IDisposable. And since information is sparse, it might suggest that it wasn't intended for static usage. Instead I chose to reuse the [BaseClientService.Initializer](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Services_1_1BaseClientService) and make that static instead (one of its dependencies is the certificate). This construct performs well and now the wait time is 99% done in the GA API invocation (as it should).

Thanks.